# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el texto de un textbox desde una clase?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy intentando cambiar el texto de un `textbox` desde dentro de una clase pero no soy capaz, el caso es que dentro de la clase obtengo información y quiero que se muestre en el `textbox`, es un `windows form`.
El caso es que la clase es de un cliente tcp asincrónimo y salta una vez recibo datos del servidor, son esos datos los que quiero escribir en el textbox

Ejemplo:

```
namespace Proyecto
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public class Client 
        {
            public void EndRead(IAsyncResult result) //esta función es la que salta cuando recibo los datos, no la llamo yo, es automática
            {
                if(tcpClient == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    var buffer = (byte[])result.AsyncState;
                    var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
                    var bytesAvailable = ns.EndRead(result);


                  textBox6.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable); //esto no funciona pues no tengo acceso al form

                    BeginRead(); //esto es otra función
                } catch (Exception e)
                {

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

He probado algunas cosas que he encontrado por internet sin solución alguna y se me está haciendo bastante complicado

Gracias por las respuestas

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Volvamo atras.. ahora esa funcion EndRead, no esta en tu form? donde es que esta? si esta en tu form, deberia poder modificar el textbox sin problemas

Comment: @gbianchi perdón se me ha escapado, va dentro de una clase llamada client, acabo de actualizar el código, es exactamente como está arriba lo único que no he añadido el resto de funciones (para enviar datos, conectar al cliente,etc, que van dentro de la clase de client)

Comment: Porfa.. sueno pesado, pero es para que se entienda. Como esta ahora, parece que esa clase esta adentro de tu form. Es asi? o esta en otro lado? A veces parecen detalles bobos, pero para quien trata de responderte, toda la informacion es importante, ya que no vemos lo que vos estas viendo ;)

Comment: @gbianchi está exactamente donde se ve arriba, la clase client dentro de "public partial class Form1 : Form" y la función que salta automáticamente y me da los datos está dentro de la clase client

Comment: La clase client se puede modificar o tiene que tener exactamente esa firma? se le pueden agregar eventos, o modificar sus propiedas? el constructor tiene alguna firma en particular?

Comment: @gbianchi la clase es una clase normal, no le he tocado nada más que escribir eso, le puedo añadir todas las funciones que quiera si es a lo que te refieres ya que lo de la firma y modificar sus propiedades no sé hacerlo

Comment: La firma, es la forma en la que se escribe el constructor. y las propiedades son las variables de la clase ;).. Entonces hay una forma simple de hacerlo... pasarle el textbox en el constructor y modificarlo como quieras.

Comment: @gbianchi gracias, he buscado información pero no me queda muy claro cómo puedo pasarle el textbox en el constructor

Comment: Te añado una respuesta utilizando los comentarios que te han aportado y añadiendo una solución para el problema de los hilos que te dará.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno voy a responderte teniendo en cuenta los comentarios que te han ido aportando.

En el constructor de la clase cliente le he pasado el `Form1` puedes pasarle directamente el `TextBox` si lo prefieres.

Por otro lado entiendo que vas a rellenar el `TextBox` desde un hilo que no es el principal, para evitar problemas usamos el `InvokeRequired`

Con todo esto tu código debería quedar mas o menos así:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

}

public class Client
{
    private Form1 form;
    public Client(Form1 form)
    {
        this.form = form;
    }
    public void EndRead(IAsyncResult result) //esta función es la que salta cuando recibo los datos, no la llamo yo, es automática
    {


        if (tcpClient == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            var buffer = (byte[])result.AsyncState;
            var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
            var bytesAvailable = ns.EndRead(result);

            MethodInvoker methodInvokerDelegate = delegate ()
                { this.form.textBox6.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable); };

            //This will be true if Current thread is not UI thread.
            if (this.form.textBox6.InvokeRequired)
                this.form.textBox6.Invoke(methodInvokerDelegate);
            else
                methodInvokerDelegate();


            BeginRead(); //esto es otra función
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Espero que te ayude y cualquier duda comenta aquí e intentamos aclarártela.

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, el caso es que al agregar eso cuando llamo a la clase ( con new Client(); ) me dice que no se ha dado ningún argumento que corresponda al parámetro formal requerido 'form' de 'Form1.Client.Client(Form1)', lo único que me da por válido es new Client(null); que intuyo que obviamente así no funciona puesto que efectivamente me tira error una vez salta la función de la clase

Comment: Claro, debes añadirle el formulario como parámetro al constructor. Algo como `new Client(form1)`. Donde form1 es el objeto de tipo `Form1`.

Comment: gracias de nuevo por tomarte tu tiempo con esto, el caso es que si pongo new Client(form1) me pone que 'form1' no existe en el contexto actual y si pongo new Client(Form1) Form1 en mayúscula me pone 'Form1' es tipo, que no es válida en el contexto indicado

Comment: Creas el objeto Client desde el formulario? Si es asi debes poner `new Client(this)`. Donde this es el objeto que representa a tu formulario.

Comment: Muchas gracias! sí lo llamaba desde dentro del formulario, con new Client(this) me ha funcionado perfectamente, un saludo